# How to setonItemClickListner on ImageButton using RecyclerView in android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am trying to implement OnItemClick on image button using User Defined Interface.

This is **user defined** Interface which i used for on ImageButton Click.

```
public interface OnItemClickListener {

public boolean onItemClick(int position,HashMap<ArrayList<String>,ArrayList<String>> ash);
```

}

**This is RecyclerView Adapter**

```
 public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
    TextView id, name, price, txt_counter, txt_CalculatePrice;
    Spinner spinner;
    Button add, minus;
    ImageView favoriteImg;
    int quantity = 0;
    LinearLayout mLayout;

    public MyViewHolder(final View itemView) {
        super(itemView);


        favoriteImg = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imgbtn_favorite);
        txt_counter = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_Quantity);
        txt_CalculatePrice = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.price_Calculation);
        mLayout = (LinearLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.button_holder);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (mItemClickListener != null) {
            mItemClickListener.onItemClick(v, getLayoutPosition(), uniqueData);
        }
    }
}

public interface OnItemClickListner {
    public void onItemClick(View view, int Position, HashMap<ArrayList<String>, ArrayList<String>> ash);
}

public void SetOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListner mItemClickListener) {
    this.mItemClickListener = mItemClickListener;
}
```

**This is Fragment**

```
productListAdapter.SetOnItemClickListener(new ProductListAdapter.OnItemClickListner() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(View view, int Position, HashMap<ArrayList<String>, ArrayList<String>> ash) {
                    AddToDatabase(view,Position,ash,list,hashmap,dataArrayList);
                }
            });
            productListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            productListView.setAdapter(productListAdapter);

        }
```

My Current code is working properly, however following code

```
productListAdapter.SetOnItemClickListener(new ProductListAdapter.OnItemClickListner()
```

is resulting me on a complete row click (Complete View), instead i am looking for Particular image button click.

Answer (score 1):

Simply change the following in your `ViewHolder`:

```
itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
```

To this:

```
favoriteImg.setOnClickListener(this);
```